# Is Plop! a sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is the word plop in this example a sentence of its own?

> Plop! The ripe, juicy fig fell smack into the umbrella.

Comment: No, it's not a sentence. It's an onomatopoeic word -- i.e, a word intended to sound like a particular thing, in this case (say) the sound made by an overripe fruit falling. Sentences have subjects and verbs. _Plop_ is neither.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I agree that "plop!" isn't a sentence, but I don't agree that sentences must have subjects and verbs (agreeing with rogermue below).  Consider, "He says "Nonsense!", and I say so, too."

Comment: Tell us your definition of "sentence" and, well, you probably won't need to ask the question any more.

Comment: While it's not a sentence itself, it's absolutely fine in your example. Having interjections (or single onomatopoeic words) can really make a story more inclusive and interesting.

Comment: It's a **holophrasm** https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holophrasis

Answer (score 2):

There are one-word sentences that are not conform to the normal sentences with subject and predicate. One-word sentences as yes, no, please, now, never etc must be seen as a sentence type of its own. And I would see "Plop!" as a one-word sentence describing exactly the sound your ice cream ball makes when it falls to the ground.

I understand John Lawler's view and can accept it as well. I think the matter is a thing of personal preference. And the whole question is a bit academic. Comics use a lot of such sound describing words and we don't have any difficulty understanding them, ie we don't need a grammar explanation.

Comment: Cool with me if you want to use a wider set by a wider definition for _sentence_. But the set consists of disjoint subsets -- those that have a subject and verb and those that don't -- and it's the latter I'm interested in, but the OP might prefer the broader definition.

Answer (score 2):

"In grammatical use, though *not in popular language*, a ‘sentence’ may consist of a single word..." (from the [OED](http://oed.com/), **sentence**, emphasis mine). In grammatical use, either the subject or the predicate may be omitted by ellipsis. Here, "plop" can be construed as a predicate consisting of an intransitive verb meaning 'fell with a sound like that of an object falling into water without splashing' (paraphrased from [**plop**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plop)), with the subject (the fig) omitted.

In both grammatical use and popular language, calling "Plop!" an 'interjection' instead of a 'sentence' will work:

> in·ter·jec·tion n.
>
> 1. A sudden, short utterance; an ejaculation.
> 2. Abbr. interj. or int.
>
> a. The part of speech that usually expresses emotion and *is capable of standing alone*.
>
> b. Any of the words belonging to this part of speech, such as Ugh! or Wow!

(From interjection. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved September 24 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interjection. Emphasis mine.)